# return array of strings from soap to android

Tags: java, android, arrays, web-services, ksoap2

I'm using Soap web service for android and it's should return array of strings , but I'm facing some problem in retrieving array or array elements

but i have some other array of integer and works fine !

```
    try {
    SoapObject request5 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE5, METHOD_NAME5);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport5 = new HttpTransportSE(URL5);
    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("TID");
    pi.setValue(TID);
    pi.setType(Integer.class);
    request5.addProperty(pi);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request5);


        androidHttpTransport5.call(SOAP_ACTION5, envelope);

        // HERE IS THE PROBLEM 
        Object  result=  envelope.getResponse();  



        String str = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < (result).getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            str = ((String) ( result).getProperty(i).toString());

            StudentIdList.add(get(str));

        }

        p.setids(StudentIdList);

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        p.seterror("error");
        return p;

    }

    catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        p.seterror("error");
        return p;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        p.seterror(e.toString());
        return p;
    }
```

log :

```
  The method getProperty(int) is undefined for the type Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Object  result=  envelope.getResponse();
```

To this:

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

**Detail:**  `(result).getPropertyCount()` and `(result).getProperty(i)` can not be executed. They are going to cause a compile error because your current `result` definition is an `Object` and there are no methods like `getPropertyCount` and `getProperty` for `Object` type. So You must cast your response to `SoapObject`.